# jQuery Mobile Scroll Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Having issues with getting the scroll series of events to function (at all, not just as designed).  Have been trawling through all articles, code suggestions and other help topics regarding this, but no-one can explain why this example doesn't work at all:

Basic page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>JQM Test</title>

   <script src="/inc/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
   <script src="/inc/jQuery/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var scroll = 0;
   $(function() {
       $(window).on('scroll',function(e) {
           console.log("Scrolled - "+scroll);
           scroll++;
       });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    Contents blah blah.
</body>
</html>
```

Ok so the inclusion files need substituting if you copy paste, and version may be differnet.  Anwyays onto the behaviour.  When I take out the jquery.mobile inclusion the script works as expected, logging scroll notes into the console whenever scroll position is altered.

When I include the jquery.mobile it fires once when the page loads and thats it.  Have tried document/window changes in the jquery script section, scrollstart and scrollstop events.  Even tried explicitly binding an even to the scroll using native javascript.  Same result, all works fine without jqm inclusion, fails when I include the jqm.

Can someone explain to me why the JQM stuff breaks the scroll functions?

EDIT:

THe following JS functions have been attempted with the EXACT same result (function until JQM inclusion added)

```
    $(document).on("scrollstart",function(){
           ****

    $(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
        ****

    $(window).on("scrollstart",function(){
           ****

    $(window).on("scrollstop",function(){
        ****


    $(document).scrollstart(function(){
           ****

    $(document).scrollstop(function(){
        ****

    $(window).scrollstart(function(){
           ****

    $(window).scrollstop(function(){
        ****

 window.onscroll=myFunction;

 document.onscroll=myFunction;

 window.attachEvent("scroll",myFunction,false);

 document.attachEvent("scroll",myFunction,false);
```

Comment: @FraserCrosbie I am adding an edit that explicitly includes all these suggestions that do not work.  I did mention that I have tried all these, same result.

Comment: Ya, saw that right after I commented. Your code works fine on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nzwodyte/. What browser/os are you using?

Comment: I use chrome + firefox for all development, same result on both.  Your jsfiddle doesn't include a jqm frameowkr file.  Add in :     <script src="/inc/jQuery/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: It does, have a look at the external resources

Comment: okay, so it has to be something with the jquery and jqm being combined.  Weird as my JQM doesn't work without the jquery base??? do you have a merged one?

Comment: I have jquery in there too. Click the gear icon in the javascript panel.

Comment: Here is one with more styling. same code. https://jsfiddle.net/nzwodyte/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98298/discussion-between-elzaer-and-fraser-crosbie).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   $(function() {
       $(window).on('scroll',function(e) {
           console.log("Scrolled - "+scroll);
           window.scrollBy(100, 0); // for scroll horizontally.
       });
   });
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, but the problem is that the event is not trigerring due to something in JQM, doesn't matter what you put inside the function it doesn't fire unless I don't include the JQM framework JS file.

Comment: try window.onReady() function for that, is that work?

Answer (score 0):

With help from @FraserCrosbie turns out it was a bit of CSS I was ignoring: https://jsfiddle.net/nzwodyte/4/

The CSS was assigned to a `[data-role=page]{` elements and had the `height: 100%` and  `position: relative` tags.

Didn't realise that JQM was assigning data-role="page" to elements in my HTML without my declaration of said tags.

So for anyone with the same issues, check height and position CSS of your pages (from a debug point of view, not in the original DOM)